# On the Condorcet Paradox

Tags: combinatorics, voting-theory

The OEIS sequence [A277935](https://oeis.org/A277935) gives the number of ways 2n-1 people can vote on three candidates such that the [Condorcet paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_paradox) arises. Is there a general formula for the number of ways $n$ people can vote on $k$ candidates so that the Condorcet paradox arises?

Comment: What about the formula written, just under the sequence in the OEIS website ?

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues, I am not sure, but I think it only applies to the condition in the question and may not apply to the general case. Do you think it works?

Comment: Paradox Condorcet with 3 candidates, it is clear. But definition of Paradox Condorcet for more than 3 candidates, it is not so clear. What is your definition (as precise as possible) ?